# Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 when I query an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api

I know that the question is findable on the forum but no answer works for me. I have an angular service that calls a nodeJS API like this:

**Angular service**

```
public createUser(pUser: User): Observable<User> {
    var url = "http://localhost:5000/users";
    var json = JSON.stringify(pUser)
    return this.http.post<User>(url, pUser)
  }
```

**NodeJS API**

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    User.create({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password })
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The API is well called, the insertion into database works, but I have this message in the browser:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0

The status of the request is 200 on return but the error is still present in the browser

I do not know if the problem comes from the front end or the backend.

After doing some research, I try to parse my object before sending it. I try to stringify too.

Without success

Is this someone would have the solution? thank you very much

Comment: The API is probably parsing the JSON for you, so you're trying to parse the string "[Object ..."

Comment: I also have the error when I send the data directly without parse

Comment: Well the key is to figure out what's in the actual HTTP data. Your browser has a "Network" developer tab that'll tell you that.

Comment: I looked, I can not find anything except status 200. The request payload is {email: "b", password: "b"}

Comment: what about the *response* body?

Comment: It just contains: OK

Comment: Well "OK" is invalid JSON :)

Comment: What should the nodeJS API return? How to do in my backend ?

Comment: Well you can do whatever you want, but if you tell the browser to expect JSON it has to be JSON.  If you don't care about the content just send "{}" or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to parse invalid *JSON*.

Due to the default response type for angular is *JSON* and the default response of code 200 is 'OK'. You have to adapt one of them.

You can change the response type to `text` like this:

```
this.http.post<User>(url, pUser, {responseType: 'text'});
```

Or you return a JSON object:

```
res.status(200).send({ status: 'OK'});
```

Comment: +1 Thank you! My Nodejs server code has `res.sendStatus(200);` for my patch request and your answer fixed it like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

It is good practise to send status 204 (No Content) if You don't send any content in response:

`res.sendStatus(204);`

Your Angular App should handle it and will not throw an error.

If You send status 200, it's good to add some json object, e.g. `{status: "OK"}` in `res.status(200).send({status: "OK"})`. Otherwise You will send the string 'OK' and will get "Unexpected token O ..." (O from 'OK').

From Express doc:
`res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')`